# UITextField with round corners and shadow but without border

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextfield, border, shadow

I want to create a subclass of `UITextField` with custom rounded corners and a shadow around, here is what I tried:

```
class TextField: UITextField {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupUI()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupUI()
    }
    private func setupUI() {
        font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        textColor = .black         
        layer.cornerRadius = 14.0
        layer.borderWidth = 0.0
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        layer.shadowRadius = 24.0
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 8)
        placeholder = "test"
    }
}
```

However, there isn't any shadow that appears around my text field:

[image]

I tried playing with `clipsToBounds` and `layer.masksToBounds` properties, but with no success. What should I do?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give it a background color.

And, if you really want a corner radius of **14**, you'll probably want to change the default insets:

```
class TextField: UITextField {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupUI()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupUI()
    }
    private func setupUI() {

        // add background color
        backgroundColor = .white
        
        font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        textColor = .black
        layer.cornerRadius = 14.0
        layer.borderWidth = 0.0
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        layer.shadowRadius = 24.0
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 8)
        placeholder = "test"

    }
    
    // adjust as desired
    var textPadding = UIEdgeInsets(
        top: 10,
        left: 20,
        bottom: 10,
        right: 20
    )
    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        let rect = super.textRect(forBounds: bounds)
        return rect.inset(by: textPadding)
    }
    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        let rect = super.editingRect(forBounds: bounds)
        return rect.inset(by: textPadding)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Yeah it was because of the `backgroundColor`, thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I made one extension for make rounded corners with shadow to any View like UIView,UIButton,UITextField etc.

```
extension UIView
{
    func addCornerEffects(cornerRadius : CGFloat = 0, fillColor : UIColor = .white, shadowColor : UIColor = .clear, shadowOffset : CGSize, shadowOpacity : Float, shadowRadius : CGFloat, borderColor : UIColor, borderWidth : CGFloat)
    {
       self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
       self.layer.shadowColor = shadowColor.cgColor
       self.layer.shadowOffset = shadowOffset
       self.layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
       self.layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
       self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
       self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
       self.layer.backgroundColor = nil
       self.layer.backgroundColor = fillColor.cgColor
    }
}
```

You can use this in viewDidLoad in your ViewController like as below

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) 
{
    self.txtFirstName.addCornerEffects(cornerRadius: 14, fillColor: .white, shadowColor: UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2), shadowOffset: CGSize(width: 0, height: 8), shadowOpacity: 1.0, shadowRadius: 25.0, borderColor: .clear, borderWidth: 0)
}
```

Here is output

[image]